# How can I create a user-specific HOSTS File?

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-xp, user-profiles, hosts-file

I know that by editing my [HOSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`), I can block any site, but I would like to take this a step further.

Is it possible (in Windows XP or newer) to have different version of this file for my Guest user?

Comment: Not easily. The hosts file is where the system first checks to see if a requested address has an immediate resolution. The entire system uses this file. A potential solution may be too have a scheduled task that when the user logs in you swap the file but the task will need admin rights. You will then need to revert the file for your other users so they, too, will need some script. Is there a better solution such as a proxy server or firewall application you could use? What are you trying to block?

Comment: I am trying to block all video web sites for my Guest user.Rather than using other third party tools(e.g. family safety).I guess I am comfortable with if just a script solve my problem.

Comment: It can't do this automatically, but you can write a batch file to get the job done.

Comment: You might get some even more suitable help of you asked the question describing what you're *actually* trying to do. There are more ways to block sites than to only use the `HOSTS` file.

Comment: Hi Twisty! can you suggest some readings regarding user specific site-blocking using some scripts ( I mean without using any 3rd party tools )? And also other ways rather than editing my `hosts` file.

Comment: Any chance this answer has changed in the last 4 years? Is there a method or app to provide the equivalent of a *"per-user `HOSTS` file"?*

Comment: No. The hosts file still behaves the same way it has for a long time.